# Jquery detecting clicked element id

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the same function to slide up and down a text area. using jquery's slidetoggle.

How can I make javascript detect the clicked element in order to know which box to expand.

Here is what I have

```
function slidedown(id){



        $(id+'text').slideToggle(500);  


}
```

that is my function

in my html I have this

```
<a id="reroof" href="javascript:slidedown(this)">reroof</a>
```

the section i want to expand is called rerooftext

however when I check the value of id.id I says undefined.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following code:

**html code:**

```
<a id="reroof" href="#" onclick="javascript:slidedown(this)">reroof</a>
```

**JS code:**

```
function slidedown(val){   
    var id = val.id;  
    alert(id);
    $(id+'text').slideToggle(500);     
}
```

In html you are passing the element(this refers the element not an id)

**Working Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/jAkMq/

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML:

```
<a id="reroof" href="#">reroof</a>
```

In your javascript:

```
$("#reroof").click(function (e) { 
    var id = "#" + this.id + "text";
    $(id).slideToggle(500);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: this would mine knowing the name of the div id, thats what I want javascript to detect.

Comment: @user541597 You can replace `$("#reroof")` with whatever selector you want. `$('a')`, for example, would apply this function to all links on your page. You wouldn't need to know the ids of any of them.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a id="reroof" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="slidedown(this)">reroof</a>
```

function slidedown(obj){

```
    $(obj.id+'text').slideToggle(500);
```

}

javascript:slidedown(this). here this will be the element not the id

Comment: try using onlick instead of href